# Improve the performance of a if else condition inside a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a VBA macro & I want to improve the performance because the macro takes ages to run.

I think that the running performance is impacted by the

`For Each rCell In .Range("O3:O" & Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` which intend to limit the loop up to the first empty row.

```
Sub E_Product_Density_Check()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set Vws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Variables")

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "Variables" Then

 Application.DecimalSeparator = ","

ws.Activate

With ActiveSheet
        For Each rCell In .Range("O3:O" & Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each iCell In .Range("N3:N" & Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each xCell In .Range("M3:M" & Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each yCell In .Range("L3:L" & Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

            If (rCell.Value / ((iCell.Value * xCell.Value * yCell.Value) / 1000000)) <= Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Name, Vws.Range("A1:E10"), 5, False) Then
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Else
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbWhite
            End If
        Next yCell
        Next xCell
        Next iCell
        Next rCell
    End With
    End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: It is hard to see what the code is doing, but nested for-loops nested to a depth of 4 is quartic complexity. `n^4` gets very large very fast. In any event, if the purpose is to color cells -- why not just use conditional formatting?

Comment: Just a guess, but I'd imagine that the 4 deep nesting of the loops has a performance hit that is exponentially greater than the `If` statement.

Comment: First, set somevalue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Name, Vws.Range("A1:E10"), 5, False) outside of the loop, and use it in your comparison, so you don't have to actually do the same vlookup on every loop

Comment: @JohnColeman - it is actually n^5, worksheets are also looped.

Comment: You might find Code Review a better place for these kind of questions : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why not have the calc at the end also, so `=if(N3/((o3.......` and do what you've done off that, or as suggested, Conditional Formatting,

Comment: @CLR It should be noted that CR has much different question standards, and that reviews would not be limited simply to performance. I.e., my review would include things like the naming and indentation...

Comment: @Comintern And it seems that OP could probably use such a review. For example, the constant accessing of individual cell values would need to be addressed.

Comment: @Comintern - thanks for clarifying. I just figured as it worked, it sat in that grey area between the two sites.

Comment: @JohnColeman Absolutely. I'm mainly pointing that out because there have been some misunderstandings in the past as to what asking for one's code to be reviewed entails.

Comment: You should load these into arrays and do your comparisons there. Will be much faster

Comment: If `i`, `x` and `y` are multiplied together : `iCell.Value * xCell.Value * yCell.Value` and `r` is changing colour, then `r` is going to be blinking merrily away as it scans `i`, `x` and `y`. Surely there should be some kind of `Exit For` in there somewhere once it goes yellow? Alternatively, what about scanning `r` and divide it by `max("M:M") * max("N:N") * max("L:L")`?

Comment: I think you don't understand what nested loops are for. The only thing you change is rCell's color. But why would you change it n^4 time if you keep only the last calculation for each set of cells? Ox's color will be determined based on Ox, Nn, Mn, and Ln, so n iterations should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub E_Product_Density_Check2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Vws As Worksheet
    Set Vws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Variables")

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ' Application.ScreenUpdating = False  (no need for this)
    Application.DecimalSeparator = ","

    Dim target As Variant
    Dim r_O As Range, r_N As Range, r_M As Range, r_L As Range
    Dim n As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Variables" Then
            ' For the target value for each worksheet
            target = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws.Name, Vws.Range("A1:E10"), 5, False)
            ' ws.Activate  (this was slow)

            'Find the number of cells in column O, and assume the same number exists in N, M & L.
            n = ws.Range(ws.Range("O3"), ws.Range("O3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
            Set r_O = ws.Range("O3")
            Set r_N = ws.Range("N3")
            Set r_M = ws.Range("M3")
            Set r_L = ws.Range("L3")

            For i = 1 To n
            ' Go down the column O
                If (r_O.Cells(i, 1).Value / ((r_N.Cells(i, 1).Value * r_M.Cells(i, 1).Value * r_L.Cells(i, 1).Value) / 1000000)) < target Then
                    r_O.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Else
                    r_O.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbWhite
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I think what you are trying to do is set the color of column O based on the values of columns M, N & L **in the same row**.

The reason I came to this conclusion is because with your code the color of column O cell is determined only by the *values in the last rows only*  since each iteration of the inner loops overwrites the same cell.

Comment: Hi @ja72, your code works perfectly and is much more performant. Thank you. I really appriciate.

Comment: Lessons learned. 1) do not use `ActiveSheet` and `.Activate` (or blind `Range()` which implies `ActiveSheet`). 2) Use the `.Cells()` propery to pull a specific cell from a table using _numeric_ values for the row and column index. 3) Do not use string math as in `"O3:O" & Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: @brice if this code answers your question to your satisfaction, you should mark it "accepted" (by selecting the check mark next to the question)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?  Snippit:

```
    Dim r as long, lr as long, myvalue as double 'r is row to iterate, lr is last row, myvalue = your vlookup
    'skipping the other code to get down to the loop
    With ActiveSheet
        myvalue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Name, Vws.Range("A1:E10"), 5, False) 'shoudl only need to find this once
        lr = .cells(.rows.count,"O").end(xlup).row
        For r = 2 to lr 'starting on 2 because 1 is probably headers
            If (.Cells(r,"O").Value / ((.Cells(r,"N").Value * .Cells(r,"M").Value * .Cells(r,"L").Value) / 1000000)) <= myvalue Then
                .Cells(r,"O").Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Else
                .Cells(r,"O").Interior.Color = vbWhite
            End If
        Next r
    End With
```

Comment: Works great too. Thanks a lot